# How do I install python libraries in raspberry pi without an internet connection?

Tags: python, installation, raspberry-pi, i2c

I have to install a few libraries in my Raspberry Pi but I cannot connect it to the internet. Is it possible to download them in a windows pc (even linux is fine) and copy them to the raspberry pi so that I can make an offline install. How is this possible?

These are the libraries I need

```
    sudo apt-get install i2c-tools
    sudo apt-get install python-smbus
```

I would also like to install this program to make it a http server

```
    sudo apt-get install lighttpd
```

I would like to download all this to windows and then copy them to the raspberry pi where I can install them. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure ,I assume you are running ubuntu in Raspberry. 
 Download the deb into Raspberry and run following command in the terminal

```
dpkg -i file_to_install.deb
```

full cheat sheet of dpkg
http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php

but there is great chance the deb packages requires other dependency packages to proceed installation. I strongly suggest using a internet connection.